# How to set Alarm on android Oreo or Above?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-8.0-oreo, background-service

I have implemented AlarmManager with background service, It works fine on devices below Oreo. But doesn't work on Android Oreo and above as Google stopped background services from working on Oreo and Above.

Is there any source code or any kind of resource which will help me to set alarms on Android Oreo or above devices?

After searching for a while I found out about JobsIntentService, but couldn't find enough information about it. And I don't know if it is the way to go. Basically, I want to show notifications on particular dates and times.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Job scheduler is a good solution, but not when you need an alarm to fire at the exact time. 
because Job Scheduler delays services to save battery power and does not work well in the dose mode.

Answer (score 4):

Please try bellow method it will work for you.

```
/**
 * Method for start Alarm on defined minute
 *  @param minutes Minute when you want to start after current time
 * @param context
 */
public static void startAlarm(Context context, int minutes) {
    Logger.print("AlarmReceiver startAlarm  called");
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, WakefulBroadcastReceiverService.class);
    alarmIntent.setAction("testAPP");
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 123451, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    manager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    long alarmPeriodicTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + Utils.getTimeInMilliSec(Constant.TimeType.MINUTE, minutes);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        manager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmPeriodicTime, pendingIntent);
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        manager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmPeriodicTime, pendingIntent);
    } else {
        manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmPeriodicTime, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work when the device is in doze mode? if it works, then it would be a big help if you share a snippet of WakefulBroadcastReceiverService, As, I have used a simple broadcast receiver which shows only notifications.

Comment: Yes, its work for me in doze mode, Better you try first.

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a try and share if it works for me too.

Comment: I didn't find your question from the link.

Comment: What should we do if we want to repeat the alarm in exact time and in doze mode?

Comment: The best way to schedule tasks is by using WorkManager.But, This doesn't ensure the exact time to fire an alarm. You can find more on this from this link https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager.